# Is a label required to create an index?

Tags: java, neo4j

In using Neo4j with Cypher I never gave queries on properties a second thought with regards to labels thinking that indexes can exist independent of labels.

Without label

```
MATCH (n {displayName:"Macroautophagy"} ) RETURN n;
```

With label

```
MATCH (n:Pathway {displayName:"Macroautophagy"}) RETURN n;
```

until I was converting some Java that used both the Core API and Cypher mixed, into pure Core API.

The main reason was that my test databases were small and the queries ran in about the same time, but against a [large](https://reactome.org/) database the run time difference between the two is several minutes or more.

When I went to convert a query that was based on a property value alone and searched the Core API I only [found](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html) `findNode` or `findNodes` where each of them required a `label` parameter, and then I started to think about how Neo4j does the first query without a label.

In reading the documentation for [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/#query-schema-index) it noted

> Cypher enables the creation of indexes on one or more properties for all nodes that have a given label:
>
> An index that is created on a single property for any given label is
>   called a single-property index.
>   An index that is created on more than one property for any given label is called a composite index.

While I am fairly confident I now understand this, being new to using Neo4j with the Java API I don't want to miss something.

If using Neo4j Core API in Java to search for a node with a property and without a label given, then the only way to find the node(s) is with a full scan of all of the nodes looking for the property?

If the answer is no then the answer must include an example showing a faster way using the Neo4j Core API in Java. As I noted, it has been working fine as a Cypher query called in the Java so Cypher examples will not be accepted.

If the answer is yes then I have to ask for some supporting Neo4j documentation beyond what I noted. The reason is any one can say yes and I can't validate it based on a coding example.

---

Food for thought.

I guess the reason I never thought of indexes requiring a label is that in all of the reading about graph databases, they stress how data is not stored like tables and when thinking about indexes in a relational database you think indexes go with tables. When you break the idea of data not in tables, by default the idea of indexes tied to tables comes along for the ride and is not tied to anything but values, or so I thought, but apparently the more you learn, in this case, the more it stays the same.

Comment: Of interest: Armbruster IT Blog [Indexing overview](https://blog.armbruster-it.de/2013/12/indexing-in-neo4j-an-overview/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If using Neo4j Core API in Java to search for a node with a property
>   and without a label given, then the only way to find the node(s) is
>   with a full scan of all of the nodes looking for the property?

Yes and no.

- A standard neo4j "schema index" is always associated with a label. You already quoted the [neo4j documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/#query-schema-index-introduction) on that.
- However, [manual indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.4/indexing/) (also called "legacy" or "explicit" indexes) do not require labels. Manual indexes are only recommended for special use cases -- like [fulltext searches](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/indexing/#indexing-create-advanced), and are *much more* complex to work with than schema indexes. So, if you have an appropriate use case and you are willing to put in the considerably extra effort, then you can indeed have indexes that that are not associated with labels.

> ...apparently the more you learn, in this case, the more it stays the same.

There is a major difference between neo4j indexes and relational indexes.

- Relational DBs use indexes to speed up **joins** between table rows.
- neo4j does not use its indexes to do "joins" (relationship traversals) at all. Instead, indexes are only used to quickly find the *initial* node in a query. Subsequently, traversals of the relationships between nodes just require the use of direct addressing, which is much faster.